# Access nested object key by variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of objects like here:

```
const myArray = [{
    name: "FirstObj",
    things: {
        firstThing: "something",
        secondThing: "anotherThing"
    }
}, {
   name: "OtherObjWithVeryLongName",
   things: {
       firstThing: "something",
       secondThing: "anotherThing"
   }
}]
```

I need to access `.length` property of properties of an object to find the 
 number of characters of the longest string among speciffic keys from the array like here:

```
myFun(prop) {
    const lengths = myArray.map(object => object[prop].length);
    const longest = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);
    return longest;
}
```

The code above works when i try `myFun("name")` it returns the number of characters of the longest `.name` property among the objects in `myArray`, however when i try to access the properites of the nested object like `myFun("things.firstThing")` it clearly does not work (as I actually expected).

Is there a simple way to reorganize `myFun(prop)` so i can acces the `.length` property no matter how deep it is nested in the object?

Unfortunatelly in real life I have much more nested stuff then in this simplified example.

Comment: Well you obviously have to code it in a way that you can access nested structures. You could do that by passing an array of props, or by using the dot notation and split the props inside your function.

Comment: The good way is to split by point character and loop over its result. Or the evil way: `.map((o, i) => eval("myArray[" + i + "]." + prop + ".length"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use reduce to enable nested keys:

```
 myFun(...props) {
  const lengths = myArray.map(object => props.reduce((obj,key) => obj[key], object).length);
  const longest = Math.max(...lengths);
  return longest;
}
```

Its then usable as

```
myFun("some","nested","prop");
```

---

Improved version:

```
const myFun (...props) => myArray.reduce(
  (max, object) => Math.max(max, props.reduce((o,k) => o[k], object)),
  0
);
```